# Cambiar valores input con javascript según campo en mysql

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

A ver si alguien me puede echar una mano. He creado una aplicación para la comunidad de vecinos para que los vecinos vean los gastos, documentos y más información.

Hay un formulario donde se ingresan los apuntes bancarios, necesito crear plantillas para que todos los que hagan la función de meter datos pongan los mismos valores en el resto de inputs. He creado un código, pero este no me hace nada y creo que está correcto.

```
<form name="formulario" action="../../../model/mov_cuenta/insert_mov_cuenta.php" id="formulario" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <br>
                <label class="form-label-forms">Tipo </label><br>
                <select class="form-input-forms" id="tipo" onchange="cargarValorDesdeMySQL()" name="tipo">
                    <option value="" disabled selected>Selecciona</option>
                    <?php
                    $query = "select DISTINCTROW nombre from tipos order by nombre asc";
                    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
                    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                        echo '<option value="' . $row['nombre'] . '">' . $row['nombre'] . '</option>';
                    }
                    ?>
                </select><br><br>
```

---

Parte javascript en el mismo archivo

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function cargarValorDesdeMySQL() {

    // Obtén el valor seleccionado del campo de selección
    var tipoSeleccion = document.getElementById('tipo').value;

    // Realiza una solicitud AJAX a PHP para obtener el valor desde MySQL
    if (tipoSeleccion !== '') {
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
                // Asigna el valor obtenido desde MySQL al segundo input
                document.getElementById('concepto').value = this.responseText;
                document.getElementById('contacto').value = this.responseText;
                document.getElementById('cantidad').value = this.responseText;
                document.getElementById('operacion').value = this.responseText;
                document.getElementById('vivienda').value = this.responseText;
                document.getElementById('id_mantenimiento').value = this.responseText;
                document.getElementById('descripcion').value = this.responseText;
            }
        };
        // Envía el valor seleccionado al script PHP
        xhttp.open('GET', '../../../model/plantillas/checkTemplate.php?tipo=' + tipoSeleccion, true);
        xhttp.send();
    } 
} </script>
```

El archivo php checkTemplate.php

```
    <?php

// Obtén la opción seleccionada desde la URL
$tipo = $_GET['tipo'];

$query_total = "id_tem, tipo, concepto, contacto, concat(cantidad,' €') cantidad, operacion, vivienda, id_mantenimiento, descripcion";
$query = "Select {$query_total} from template where tipo = ?";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param('s',$tipo);
    $stmt->execute();   
    $result = $stmt->get_result();      

    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $concepto = $row['concepto'];
        $contacto = $row['contacto'];
        $cantidad = $row['cantidad'];
        $operacion = $row['operacion'];
        $vivienda = $row['vivienda'];
        $id_mantenimiento = $row['id_mantenimiento'];
        $descripcion = $row['descripcion'];

    }
    
    echo ' concepto: ' . $concepto . ' - cantidad : ' . $cantidad .  
    ' - operacion : ' . $operacion . ' - vivienda : ' . $vivienda . 
    ' - id_mantenimiento : ' . $id_mantenimiento . ' - descripcion : ' . $descripcion;



// Cierra la conexión a la base de datos y statement
$stmt->close();
$conn->close();

?>
```

Muchas gracias

Comment: Hola. ¿Qué significa exactamente que el código *no hace nada*? ¿Muestra error en algún lado? ¿Has revisado la consola del navegador? ¿Has depurado algo? ¿Con qué resultados? Pon por ejemplo un `alert(xhttp.responseText);` y dinos si ves la respuesta del servidor. Por cierto, para **todo** lo relativo a tu petición Ajax, en vez de usar `this` deberías usar `xhttp`, que es la variable que usaste para declarar la petición: `var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();`, no sé por qué usas `this` ¿? [Revisa los ejemplos de la doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/responseText).

Comment: Hola Cedano,

He puesto varios console logs para que me valores de variables  if (tipoSeleccion !== '') {let xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); console.log('tipo : ' + tipoSeleccion); console.log('xhttp : ' + xhttp } xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {console.log('readystate : ' + xhttp.readyState);console.log('status : ' + xhttp.status); let data = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);  console.log(data);if (xhttp.readyState === 4 && xhttp.status === 200) { console.log('estoy dentro'); console.log(xhttp.responseText); document.getElementById('concepto').value = data.concepto;

Comment: En data ha de recoger los valores de la query. La query me funciona bien. Me da los valores correctos . Lo he comprobado con la url  https://192.168.2.2:8084/model/plantillas/checkTemplate.php?tipo=Cobro%20Comunidad

Answer (score 0):

RESUELTO.
He añadido un array en el while fetch_assoc

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

    $data[] = array(
        'concepto' => $row['concepto'],
        'contacto' => $row['contacto'],
        'cantidad' => $row['cantidad'],
        'operacion' => $row['operacion'],
        'vivienda' => $row['vivienda'],
        'id_mantenimiento' => $row['id_mantenimiento'],
        'descripcion' => $row['descripcion']
    );

} 
//Convierte los datos a formato JSON y envíalos al cliente
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($data);
```

Finalmente esta es la función java script.

He ido haciendo console.log hasta conseguir los el array data y ver cada elemento del array (la fila del registro)

Postiormente envio dicho valor al getElementId que le corresponde.

```
function cargarValorDesdeMySQL() {

    // Obtén el valor seleccionado del campo de selección
    let tipoSeleccion = document.getElementById('tipo').value;
    let radioGasto = document.getElementById('gasto');
    let radioIngreso = document.getElementById('ingreso');

    // Realiza una solicitud AJAX a PHP para obtener el valor desde MySQL
    if (tipoSeleccion !== '') {
        let xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        console.log('tipo : ' + tipoSeleccion);
        console.log('xhttp : ' + xhttp);
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            console.log('readystate : ' + xhttp.readyState);
            console.log('status : ' + xhttp.status);

            if (xhttp.readyState === 4 && xhttp.status === 200) {

                console.log('estoy dentro');
                let jsonResponse = xhttp.responseText;
                if (jsonResponse.trim() !== '') {
                    try {

                        let data = JSON.parse(jsonResponse);
                        // Accede a los valores del objeto JSON
                        let concepto = data[0].concepto;
                        console.log('concepto : ' + concepto);
                        let contacto = data[0].contacto;
                        console.log('contacto : ' + contacto);
                        let cantidad = data[0].cantidad;
                        console.log('cantidad : ' + cantidad);
                        let operacion = data[0].operacion;
                        console.log('operacion : ' + operacion);
                        let vivienda = data[0].vivienda;
                        console.log('vivienda : ' + vivienda);
                        let id_mantenimiento = data[0].id_mantenimiento;
                        console.log('id_mantenimiento: ' + id_mantenimiento);
                        let descripcion = data[0].descripcion;
                        console.log('descripcion : ' + descripcion);


                        document.getElementById('concepto').value = concepto;
                        if (operacion === 'gasto') {
                            // Si el valor de operacion es 'gasto', selecciona el radio 'gasto'
                            radioGasto.checked = true;
                        } else if (operacion === 'ingreso') {
                            // Si el valor de operacion es 'ingreso', selecciona el radio 'ingreso'
                            radioIngreso.checked = true;
                        }

                        // ... y así sucesivamente
                    } catch (e) {
                        console.error('Error al analizar la respuesta JSON:', e);
                    }
                } else {
                    console.error('La respuesta JSON está vacía.');
                }

            }
        };
        // Envía el valor seleccionado al script PHP
        xhttp.open('GET', '../../../model/plantillas/checkTemplate.php?tipo=' + tipoSeleccion, true);
        xhttp.send();
    }
}
```